# why cannot access private data member in cpy c-tor?

Tags: c++

I created a cpy c-tor for deep copy but to access my private member data i had to write the getter function, why? the cpy c-tor is a member of my class?

```
class Person                        
{
    int* p;
public:
    Person() { p = new int; }
    Person(int e)
    {
        p = new int;
        *p = e;
    }
    Person(const Person& o)     /*doesn't work here */
    {
        p = new int;
        *p = o->p;
    }
    ~Person() { delete p; }
    void display(void)const
    {
        std::cout << "the value is: " << *p << std::endl;
    }
    void set_val(int s)
    {
        *p = s;
    }
    int get_val(void)const
    {
        return *p;
    }
};
```

but here it works

```
Person(const Person& o)
    {
        p = new int;
        *p = o.get_val();
    }
```

Comment: Syntax error. Use `*p = *(o.p);`, not `o->p`. Voting to close for typo.

Answer (score 2):

In your copy constructor, you're taking a `Person` by reference:

```
Person(const Person& o)
```

But you're trying to dereference that `Person` object as if it was a pointer:

```
*p = o->p;
```

Remember that `->` is just syntactic sugar for dereference-dot, so what you're actually doing is:

```
*p = (*o).p;
```

When you really want:

```
*p = *(o.p);
```

In other words, "Get the `p` integer pointer on the `o` Person and dereference it."

Comment: thank you but I can't understand, can you explain a little bit please

Comment: What don't you understand, @Backik?

Comment: the difference between (*o).p and *(o.p) because I already know this: (*o).p is equal to o->p
why not o.*p?

Comment: in `(*o).p` you are dereferencing `o` … in `*(o.p)` you are dereferencing `p`

Comment: @Backick. `o` is not a pointer. You can't dereference it.